# pandas.nlargest() - Confused with repeated index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following sample DataFrame defined as following:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {"Age":[28, 3, 32, 18], "Student":[False, True, False, False]}, index = ["Jack", "Sam", "Nate", "Jack"])
```

and the output is following.

[image]

If I want to extract 2 rows with largest Age values, I use `pandas.nlargest(2, "Age")` and the output has 3 rows instead of two as following:

[image]

If I try for 4 largest Age values using `pandas.nlargest(4, "Age")`, the result is more confusing as following:

[image]

I am confused on understanding the reason behind it.

Comment: What version of 'pandas' do you use? I tried your example and it works correctly: 'df1.nlargest(2, 'Age')' returns two rows with largest 'Age'. Also see https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13412 I used pandas ver. 0.19.2

Comment: The version is 0.19.1. I also tried online python shells, but the result is the same.

Comment: @user35603 I updated and the issue is resolved. I really appreciate a lot. You saved me from an hours of headache

Comment: @user35603, i think you should post it as an answer - this might help others, having the same issue...

Comment: Thanks MaxU, hope it might help someone. I've already done it.

Comment: I'm happy to help ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is resolved. Pandas version I was using was 0.19.1 and after [suggestion of @user35603](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189312/pandas-nlargest-confused-with-repeated-index-values#comment71541579_42189312) I updated it to 0.19.2 and re-executed the code and it works!

Thank you [user35603](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189312/pandas-nlargest-confused-with-repeated-index-values#comment71541579_42189312)!

The following bug was fixed in [Pandas 0.19.2](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/whatsnew.html):

- Bug in `DataFrame.nlargest` and `DataFrame.nsmallest` when the index had duplicate values ([GH13412](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13412))

Note: The [bug still remains](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13412) on the nlargest function when applied on count function

Answer (score 0):

I am working with an Excel spreadsheet and am also having this issue with nlargest. I am also using 0.19.2 and still having this problem. The index values do repeat in my sheet.  However there is no issue unless CELL-values are also repetitive.  example:

```
new = dataframe.nlargest(5, "DEF") -- only taking 5 largest values
print(new.loc[:, "DEF"])
```

prints:

```
Player
Player 1    39.0
Player 2    36.0
Player 3    36.0
Player 2    36.0
Player 3    36.0
Player 4    34.0      
Player 1    34.0
Player 5    34.0
Player 4    34.0
Player 1    34.0
PLayer 5    34.0
Name: DEF, dtype: float64
```

-- I am getting 11 values instead of 5... it SHOULD give me this:

```
Player
Player 1    39
Player 2    36
Player 3    36
Player 4    34
Player 1    34
```

BUT nlargest works for me if cell values dont repeat.. example:

```
new = all_rounds.nlargest(5, "Frags")
print(new.loc[:, "Frags"])

prints:
Player
Player 1    117.0
Player 2    112.0
Player 2    105.0
Player 3    103.0
PLayer 4    102.0
Name: Frags, dtype: float64
```

-- this is correct.

There seems to be a problem with using nlargest on an Excel dataframe when there are cell-value repeats. Unless I am missing something.